Is the koch snowflake curve a differentiable manifold?
I would argue that the Koch Snowflake curve is not a differentiable manifold.
Here's why:
The Koch Snowflake(see here) is a compact set. If it were a differentiable manifold, we would be able to cover the curve with a finite number of local $C^1$ parameterizations. Each of these local parameterizations would correspond to a smooth ($C^1$) curve, meaning that each segment would have finite arc length. However, this leads to a contradiction. Since the Koch Snowflake has infinite arc length, a finite number of $C^1$ parameterizations could not fully describe it, as their total arc length would necessarily be finite.
Thus, the Koch Snowflake curve cannot be a differentiable manifold.
Is my reasoning correct. I would very much appreciate feedback on the question.

I suppose by manifold you mean differentiable manifold. If that is correct: What is the differentiable structure to be checked? Or do you want to know if there is any differentiable structure making the space a differentiable manifold?

Yes I mean a differentiale manifold. I do not understand your question @Tzimmo. I would like to know if it is a differentiable manifold

@hardmath thank you for the suggestion, I have edited the question

I think you want your manifold to be embedded in $\mathbb R^2.$ Otherwise it is easy to give it a differential structure, via a homeomorphism to the circle.

@Keplerto probably. I want the image of the snowflake curve to be an differentiable manifold in $\mathbb{R}^2$. I have not written that, since I have not known that there are any other manifolds

In that case I think your reasoning is correct. If $K$ is the Koch snowflake, the crux of the issue is that $\alpha : (a, b) \to K$ is differentiable iff it is a differentiable function with codomain $\mathbb R^2.$

I do not think that I can follow you

One cannot answer this question until you clarify the meaning of the word "is."

@MoisheKohan I would guess that I mean isometric since I have not heard anything about topological manifolds

Once you figure out what your question really is, you should edit your post instead of replying in comments.

Is the koch snowflake curve a differentiable manifold?
What do you mean by "is"?
If you mean homeomorphic, then YES, the Koch snowflake is homeomorphic to a circle.
If you mean isometric, then NO, as noted: any connected subset with more than one point has infinite arclength.  No $1$-dimensional differentiable manifold has this property.  (Koch has topological dimenion $1$, so it is not a differentiable manifold of any dimension other than $1$.)

Let me get this straight. The Koch snowflake is no differentiable manifold
